# Java if Statement is not going to the correct statement

Tags: java, if-statement

This is a school program that you enter the number of checks for a bank and it calculates the cost for the month. When I put an amount over 20 checks in it uses the wrong else if statement!

Main Class:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class WeSavU
{
private int amountOfChecks, amountOver10, amountOver20, amountOver30;
private double total;
private String message, formatTotal;
public WeSavU(int checks)
{
    amountOfChecks = checks;
}


public void setNumChecks(int checks)
{
    amountOfChecks = checks;
}

public String getTotalPrice()
{
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
    if (amountOfChecks <= 10)
    {
        total = (amountOfChecks * .14) + .50;
        formatTotal = df.format(total);
        message = "Your total is: $" + formatTotal;
    }

    else if (amountOfChecks == 0 )
    {
        message = "Total is $0.50";
    }

    else if (amountOfChecks <0)
    {
        message = "Invalid amount of checks... Total is $0.50";
    }

    else if (amountOfChecks >=11)
    {
        amountOver10 = amountOfChecks - 10;
        total = (10*.14) + (amountOver10*.13) + .50;
        formatTotal = df.format(total);
        message = "Your total is: $" + formatTotal;
    }


    else if (amountOfChecks >= 21)
    {
        amountOver20 = amountOfChecks - 20;
        total = 2.7 + (amountOver20* .12) + .42;
        formatTotal = df.format(total);
        message = "Your total is: $" + formatTotal;
    }

    else if (amountOfChecks > 1000)
    {
        message = "You need a corporate account!";
    }

    else if (amountOfChecks >= 31 && amountOfChecks < 1001)
    {
        amountOver30 = amountOfChecks - 30;
        total = 3.9 + (amountOver30*.11) + .50;
        formatTotal = df.format(total);
        message = "Your total is: $" + formatTotal;
    }


    return message;
    }
    }
```

DialogBox Class:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class WeSavUDialog
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String checks;
    int Check;
    checks = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount of checks:");

    Check = Integer.parseInt(checks);

    WeSavU check = new WeSavU(Check);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, check.getTotalPrice());
}
}
```

Comment: How have you tried debugging this besides dumping your code on SO?

Comment: which else does it use and which does it suppose to use? can you mention in comments?

Comment: Your logic seems off to me `0` is less then `10`, therefore your first `if` statement is catching that as well

Comment: Im using blueJ so I had it stop if it reached: else if (amountOfChecks >= 21)
    {
        amountOver20 = amountOfChecks - 20;
        total = 2.7 + (amountOver20* .12) + .42;
        formatTotal = df.format(total);
        message = "Your total is: $" + formatTotal;
    } but it didn't so it's not going to the right statement.

Comment: @Dan Grueneberg -
Please share with us whatever evidence you have to support your claim.

Comment: Also if you enter 28 it should come out to be 4.16 but it comes out to 4.24

Comment: @Dan Grueneberg - Please look at the answers already given.  28 is more than 11, so `amountOfChecks >=11` condition is met first.

Comment: @Everyone: Please do not downvote this question. She/He is a school-goer and its totally okay for him/her to ask this question.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this condition, if amountOfChecks is 20, the below condition is satisfied and it will enter this if condition.

```
else if (amountOfChecks >=11)
```

Change it to

```
else if (amountOfChecks >= 11 && amountOfChecks < 21)
```

Comment: There are other errors like amountofChecks<0.
I have put (probably) a perfect solution below.

Comment: @ManasPaldhe I wouldn't call it a *perfect solution*, it is *A* solution, but I'm sure it can be done better

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I agree it is not perfect and can be improved. By perfect, I mean giving correct solution and not necessarily optimal.

Answer (score 0):

The if conditions are executed in order. That is causing the error.

public String getTotalPrice()
{
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

```
if (amountOfChecks == 0 )
{
    message = "Total is $0.50";
}

else if (amountOfChecks <0)
{
    message = "Invalid amount of checks... Total is $0.50";
}


else if (amountOfChecks <= 10)
{
    total = (amountOfChecks * .14) + .50;
    formatTotal = df.format(total);
    message = "Your total is: $" + formatTotal;
}

else if (amountOfChecks > 1000)
{
    message = "You need a corporate account!";
}

else if (amountOfChecks >= 31 && amountOfChecks < 1001)
{
    amountOver30 = amountOfChecks - 30;
    total = 3.9 + (amountOver30*.11) + .50;
    formatTotal = df.format(total);
    message = "Your total is: $" + formatTotal;
}

else if (amountOfChecks >= 21)
{
    amountOver20 = amountOfChecks - 20;
    total = 2.7 + (amountOver20* .12) + .42;
    formatTotal = df.format(total);
    message = "Your total is: $" + formatTotal;
}

else if (amountOfChecks >=11)
{
    amountOver10 = amountOfChecks - 10;
    total = (10*.14) + (amountOver10*.13) + .50;
    formatTotal = df.format(total);
    message = "Your total is: $" + formatTotal;
}
return message;
}
```

In your case, you will have errors for case amountOfChecks <0 also.
This is because if amountOfChecks is say -5, then after checking that it is not equal to 0 but it is less than 10, it goes into 2nd condition that amountofChecks<=10 and does not go into the required condition.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You write:

```
if(...)
else if (amountOfChecks >=11)//always stops here
{
    ...
}
else if (amountOfChecks >= 21)//never reached.
{
    ...
}
```

The first condition here always includes the second, so you will never get to the second. That is to say, the number of checks is greater than 11 whenever it is greater than 21, so you should check in greatest-to-least order, starting with `if(amount>1001)`.

Answer (score 0):

The way the current code is ordered, the code checks to see if amountOfChecks is greater than / equal to 11 before it checks for 21. Say you input 25 checks. 25 is >= 11, and it is also >= 21. Because your program checks for >= 11 first, the else if(amountOfChecks >= 21) is never reached. Either switch the order so that the larger numbers are checked first, or change it so that it checks for a range.

Example: 
    else if(amountOfChecks >= 11 && amountOfChecks<21){
}

Answer (score 0):

Take a moment to think about your logic.

Assuming that `amountOfChecks == 9`.

- `amountOfChecks <= 10` is `true`, therefore no other `if` statements are checked, meaning it's skipping `== 0` and `< 0`

A better statement would be...

```
if (amountOfChecks > 0 && amountOfChecks <= 10) {...}
else if (amountOfChecks == 0) {...}
else if (amountOfCheck < 0) {...}
```

Now, if `amountOfChecks == 11`...

- `amountOfChecks >= 11` is `true` and no more `if` statements are checked.

  else if (amountOfChecks > 10 && amountOfChecks < 21) {...}
  else if (amountOfChecks > 20 && amountOfChecks < 31) {...}
  else if (amountOfChecks > 30 && amountOfChecks < 1000) {...}
  else {...} // Everything else

You need to allow for ranges within the given `if` statement itself.

It would be very useful to (I can't believe I'm about to say this) desk check your logic with a piece of paper and pen...